# BitmapSource from embedded image

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-assembly, embedded-resource, bitmapsource

My goal is to draw image "someImage.png", which is embedded resource, on WPF window, in overridden OnRender method:

```
protected override void OnRender(System.Windows.Media.DrawingContext drawingContext)
{
    base.OnRender(drawingContext);            
    drawingContext.DrawImage(ImageSource, Rect);            
}
```

I found code to get my image from resources to Stream:

```
public BitmapSource GetSourceForOnRender()
{
    System.Reflection.Assembly myAssembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    Stream myStream = myAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream("KisserConsole.someImage.png");

    // What to do now?

    return //BitmapSource
```

}

But how can i get or create BitmapSource now?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can create a BitmapImage from the stream by setting its `StreamSource` property:

```
public BitmapSource GetSourceForOnRender()
{
    var assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    var bitmap = new BitmapImage();

    using (var stream =
        assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("KisserConsole.someImage.png"))
    {
        bitmap.BeginInit();
        bitmap.StreamSource = stream;
        bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        bitmap.EndInit();
    }

    return bitmap;    
}
```

---

That said, you would usually create a BitmapImage from a [Resource File Pack URI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx#Resource_File_Pack_URIs___Local_Assembly), like e.g.

```
new BitmapImage(new Uri(
    "pack://application:,,,/KisserConsole.someImage.png"));
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try to use this:

```
Uri uri = new Uri( $"pack://application:,,,/YourAssemblyName;component/Resources/images/photo.png", UriKind.Absolute );

BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage( uri );
```

Make sure the Build Action of the image file is set to Resource.