# How to load images xaml in WPF having build action embedded resources

Tags: wpf

How to load images xaml in WPF having build action embedded resources without changing build action of this image.

```
"<BitmapImage UriSource="pack://application:,,,/Assets/Images/clock_6.png" x:Key="clock_6"/>"
```

I tried  above but throwing "cannot locate resource" exception.

Comment: The Build Action should not be *Embedded Resource*, but instead *Resource*. Then load the image by a Resource File Pack URI, e.g. as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25714375/1136211

Comment: If you can not change the Build Action, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29198173/1136211

Comment: By images xaml do you just mean like a png file? In which case I think Clemens advice covers it.   Or is "images xaml" something else?